# Rewrite rule not working - help please

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm just having problems getting this rewrite rule working:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-].html$+) index.php?L0=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-].html$+) index.php?L0=$1&L1=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-].html$+) index.php?L0=$1&L1=$2&L2=$3 [NC,L]
```

So it changes from `index.php?L0=information` to `/information.html
and index.php?L0=information&L1=test` to `/information/test.html`
and so on...

can anyone see anything obvious to why its not working?

Comment: i assume .html must be outside the () - else you will repeat it in your url ([0-9a-zA-Z]+) and not  ([0-9a-zA-Z].html+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this redundant `+` after `$` and captured groups should not include `.html`. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z-]+)\.html$ index.php?L0=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9a-z-]+)\.html$ index.php?L0=$1&L1=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9a-z-]+)\.html$ index.php?L0=$1&L1=$2&L2=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: With `[NC]`, he can use `[0-9a-z-]` for each test and INDEX or HTML

Comment: I cant get it working with this both using NC and QSA

Comment: index.php?L0=information and the htaccess is in the same root dir as index.php

Comment: sorry me again! it works for the first rule but fails on the second

Comment: There was a typo, it is fixed now. Try again.